# Ideal energy to study higgsstrahlung at a lepton collider

Tags: collision, higgs, leptons

Referring to this diagram:

[image]

I understand that any energy excess could be taken away as kinetic energy of the final $h$ and $Z$. If you are interested in this (kind of) process should you tune the collision energy at exactly $91+125=216~$GeV or is better to go up (a bit)?

I've found [this paper in arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0676) where they claim $\sim 250~$GeV. I would like to understand how to properly select the energy in case it matters.

Comment: The higher, the better. Nothing else makes sense, anyway, they are not going to give us any more funding for a collider that can't go, at least potentially, beyond Higgs physics.

Comment: No time to write a real answer. The core problem with setting up right at threshold is that the phase-space available to the products is very small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, you don't need to tune to 'exactly' this energy but having less than $m_h + m_Z$ suppresses this diagram. Having more should typically give you a higher cross section because there is 'more phase space' the final state particles can be in, i.e. the 'excess' energy will just be used as kinetic energy of the final state particles ($Z$ and $h$ 'move faster').

On the other hand, there is a competing effect of the $Z^*$ in the s-channel being more off-shell (more away from the Z mass). The $Z$ propagator goes approximately like $\dfrac{1}{p_Z^2 - M_Z^2}$.

In the end, the cross section maximum is indeed somewhere around 250 GeV. Figure 7 of [arxiv:1308.6176](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6176) (reference 3 in the paper you refer to) shows this:

[image: Higgs cross sections in e+e- collisions]

Comment: The next accelerator will be a linear collider for exactly that reason.

Comment: Circular colliders have the advantage that one can install more than one experiment thus effectively multiplying the recorded luminosity and particles can collide more than once. Looking at Table 3 of [arxiv:1308.6176](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6176), it is expected to have a total integrated luminosity of $10\ \mathrm{ab}^{-1}$ for four detectors at TLEP240 compared to $0.25\ \mathrm{ab}^{-1}$ at ILC250.

Comment: The Next ILC will have more than one experiment. Experiment multiplicity is about controlling biases, not about increasing effective luminosity. As your own numbers show, an electron storage ring becomes inferior to a linear collider for high energies because the losses are too high.

Answer (score 0):

Completing the very good answer made by Andre Holzner, the electron and the positron in the initial state, have a non negligible probability to emit a photon with a significant energy. In particle physics jargon, this is called the ISR standing for Initial State Radiation. Therefore, you always have to be slightly above the threshold production to circumvent this problem.

Comment: Could you provide a plot or make your answer a bit more quantitative? How much could the ISR be an issue? Would you really try to compensate for it, or just ignore the events with ISR?